# Default PHP document / names needed for a Wordpress theme?

Tags: theme-development

I am hosting my own version of Wordpress, and I'd like to do a custom theme for it to suit my website.

However, with so many bits and pieces of examples on the Internet, I'm not really sure how many PHP documents I should have, and what names are they given inside a theme.

So far, i only understand that there are the following PHP documents inside a Wordpress Theme itself :

```
404.php
comments.php
footer.php
functions.php
header.php
index.php
page.php
sidebar.php
single.php
style.php
```

Are there anymore? Is there a full list that I can refer to (like a cheat sheet)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [template files list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development#Template_Files_List) in Codex contains most of the templates. See also the [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) page for dynamic, content-specific templates like `single-{post_type}.php`.

Note that a valid theme only needs to have a `style.css` and `index.php` files, all other template files are optional.